# SSRS getting data from web api with Token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, reporting-services, token

I have a front-end application(MVC 5) that connects to the web API for backend processes. The API has custom token-based authentication.

I'm trying to create some SSRS reports which will be embedded into the front end app and hoping get data from the web API to generate the reports. The connection to the API requires header values being added to the request such as the encrypted token for authentication and some other values.

Does anyone know how to do this or any articles that describe how to do this?
Any guidance or help would be appreciated.

Comment: Hi!
Any luck with this?

Comment: Yes I built it. Let me upload some solution sometime next week.